# Show that the open set in a $C_2,T_4$ space is a countable union of closed sets, without metrisation

Tags: general-topology

Now I have a topological space $X$ that is $C_2$ and $T_4$, and $U$ is an open set in it, I want to show that $U$ can be expressed as $\cup_{i\in\Bbb Z_+} F_i$ where $F_i$ are closed sets, **without the aid of any metrisation theorem** (but Uryshon's theorem about normal spaces and the equivalent Tietze extension theorem are usable, if needed).

How can I proceed then? I totally have no clue. The only thing I know is that according to $C_2$, $U$ is a countable union of base sets $B_n$. I think the next thing to do is to find a closed subset for each $B_n$ that is "saturated" enough. By $T_4$ we can find an ascending chain of open subsets $G_1\subset G_2\subset \cdots G_k\subset \cdots\subset B_n$ such that $\bar G_k\subset G_{k+1}$, but even so, there seems to be no way to guarantee that $G_k$ can literally "approach" $B_n$.

Of course, an appeal to Uryshon metrisation theorem makes this problem somewhat trivial, but is apparently an overkill here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $C_2$ means second countable, I suppose. So fix a countable base $B_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ for $X$.

Let $U$ be open. For every $x \in U$, we can apply regularity to $x$ and $U$ to get an open set $O_x$ such that $ x \in O_x \subseteq \overline{O_x} \subseteq U$. 
(This is a well-known alternative way of seeing regularity, and follows from the more standard one applied to $x$ and the disjoint closed set $X \setminus U$.)

Now we use the base: fix $n(x) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in B_{n(x)} \subseteq O_x$. Note that we also have $\overline{B_{n(x)}} \subseteq \overline{O_x} \subseteq U$.

Now, $N(U) = \{n(x) : x \in U \}$ is countable, as a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. And it's easy to see that $U = \cup_{n \in N(U)} \overline{B_n}$, and we have written $U$ as a countable union of closed sets. Why do we have this equality: for every $x \in U$ we have this $n(x)$ and this is one of the $n \in N(U)$, so $x$ is in one of these sets, and on the other hand all $\overline{B_{n(x)}}$ are subsets of $U$ by construction. So equality ensues.

Answer (score 1):

Although I never understood the "don't use this theorem blahblah..." thing, fine.

For each $x\in U$, $x$ has a closed neighborhood $F_x \subset U$. $\{{F_x}^\mathrm{o}:x\in U\}$ is an open cover of $U$. Since $U$ is itself second-countable, hence Lindelöf, there is a countable subcover $\{{F_i}^\mathrm{o}\}$. $\{F_i\}$ is what you need.

Comment: Why is $U$ Lindelöf? I think it's only true for metric spaces that $C_2\implies \text{Lindelöf}$.

Comment: No, second-countability implies Lindelöf in general. They are equivalent in metric spaces.

Comment: @Vim: always $C_2$ means every open subset is Lindelöf.

Comment: Oh sorry. You are right.

Comment: @Vim my proof makes this explicit.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thanks. It is elucidative.